# Convert an array of tuples into a hash-map in Clojure

Tags: clojure, dictionary, hashmap, tuples

I have an array of tuples, where each tuple is a 2 tuple with a key and a value. What would be the cleanest way to convert this array of tuples into a hash-map?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
user=> (into {} [[:a 1] [:b 2]])
{:a 1, :b 2}
```

Comment: Note that this also works for arrays of two-element arrays -- you'd just have to add a `(map vec ...)` around the array argument: `(into {} (map vec an-array-of-two-element-arrays))`.

Comment: And again, one of those "duh" moments you so often have while using Clojure. Nice answer.

Comment: But a relatively expensive one.

Comment: @MichałMarczyk I don't get it... if you already have an array of arrays, why map `vec` over them? I think `vec` just leaves arrays as is...

Comment: Why does it have to be vector, why doesnt a list of two element lists work?

Answer (score 7):

A map is a sequence of MapEntry elements.  Each MapEntry is a vector of a key and value.  The tuples in the question are already in the form of a MapEntry, which makes things convenient.  (That's also why the `into` solution is a good one.)

```
user=> (reduce conj {} [[:a 1] [:b 2]])
{:b 2, :a 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for good explanation! So only vector of 2 elements is MapEntry, thus  (into {} [[:a 1] {:b 2}]) will work, but (into {} ['( :a 1 ) {:b 2}]) will not work.It gets the error of "java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Keyword cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry". I wonder why can't Clojure treat all 2 elements sequence the same way in this context. It will make it more consistent. What's the reason it does not?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that "tupel" means "two-elememt array":

```
(reduce 
  (fn [m tupel] 
      (assoc m 
            (aget tupel 0) 
            (aget tupel 1))) 
  {} 
  array-of-tupels)
```

Comment: Nice. If your (to the OP) "array" is in fact a seq, instead of `(aget t n)` you can use `(t n)`, which is a bit prettier.

Comment: `(t n)` does not work with sequences. It does with vectors. But then you can simply use `(into {} array-of-vectors)` instead of the `reduce`.

Answer (score 3):

```
user=> (def a [[:a 4] [:b 6]])
user=> (apply hash-map (flatten a))
{:a 4, :b 6}
```

Comment: `flatten` is overkill for this problem.  You can take advantage of the tuples being in the form of a MapEntry (vector of key and value).

Comment: Never, ever use `flatten` for a situation like this: it will happily flatten all of your keys and values too, if they happen to be data structures!